# Kotlin sumBy function with condition

Tags: string, kotlin

Instead of using ifs and loops I would like to use sumBy function and give it a statement. Where to add condition?

`val counter = list.sumBy {it.amount}`

where amount is field from the list.

Where to add for example `if(it.flag == true)` statement?

Or just use streams?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val counter = list.sumBy { if (it.flag) it.amount else 0 }
```

or

```
val counter = list.asSequence().filter { it.flag }.sumBy { it.amount }
```

`asSequence()` for using [sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html) to prevent creataion an intermediate collection in filter function

Comment: The performance implications of sequences are a bit subtle; they avoid creating intermediate collections, but have their own overhead of extra objects to represent the lazy processing pipeline, as well as extra processing.  So they're generally not worth using unless you know your collections are likely to be big (e.g. 1000s or more).  — Either way, I prefer the `filter()` version, as that's easier to follow.

Comment: You can use `filter()` with lists as well. E.g., `val counter = list.filter(ClassName::flag).sumBy(ClassName::amount)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array by name "amount" the list then items sum will we done by this method.

```
 val amount= listOf(10, 20, 30)
    println(amount.sumBy { it })
```